# How to parse malformed html (no body tags) with BeautifulSoup in Python?

Tags: python, lxml

How to parse malformed html (no body tags) with BeautifulSoup in Python?

I have a bunch of html files to be parsed, but they do not contain the body tags, which causes problems for BeautifulSoup. See below:

```
f = "somefile.html"
html = open(f,'r').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print soup.prettify()

Output>>>

<html>
 <head>
  <title>
   Test Results
  </title>
 </head>
</html>
```

Comment: If the "problems" throw an error, use a try:except block and catch/throw the error

Comment: Don't the [tag omission rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#optional-tags) allow this to happen?